# SignalR android client can not have more than two AddMessage subscriptions

Tags: c#, android, .net, signalr

I am trying to make a chat application using SignalR between Desktop (C# - WinForms) and Android.

I have two methods in my `Hub`:

```
    public void Send(string name, string message)
    {
        Clients.All.addMessage(name, message);
    }

    public void SendAnswer(string from, string requestWas, string answer)
    {
        Clients.All.addMessage(from, requestWas, answer);
    }
```

In my android app client I connect to server on a button click, then inside the button click handler I define these two `AddMessage` subscriptions:

```
mProxy.on("AddMessage", new SubscriptionHandler2<String, String>() {
    @Override
    public void run(final String p1, final String p2) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mTvContent.append(p1 + ":\t" + p2);
            }
        });
    }
}, String.class, String.class);

mProxy.on("AddMessage", new SubscriptionHandler3<String, String, String>() {
    @Override
    public void run(final String p1, final String p2, final String p3) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mTvContent.append("-- " + p1 + " --\t" + p2 + ":\t" + p3);
            }
        });
    }
}, String.class, String.class, String.class);
```

If I use the `Send` method of the HUB, it works fine (note that it has 2 arguments hence the first `AddMessage` subscription in android code. E.G:

```
mProxy.invoke("Send", new String[]{"MobileClient", "Connected"});
```

That works fine, now if I do something with the `SendRequest` of the hub, It does not print anything on android client (the one that subscribes for 3 Strings). e.g :

```
mProxy.invoke("SendRequest", new String[]{ComConstants.MOBILE_CLIENT,
        ComConstants.LOCAL_CLIENT,
        ReqConstants.NEW_REQ});
```

But if I remove the subscription with 2 Strings, the subscription with 3 String works just fine and prints the `SendAnswer` result to the android textbox.

What I mean is, why having both `SubscriptionHandler2` and `SubscriptionHandler3` does not work at the same time? If I comment out the `SubscriptionHandler2` then the `SubscriptionHandler3` works just fine.

Any clues? maybe I am doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok....I think I should learn more about dynamic and reflection....

All I had to do was to make the following change to my c# hub:

```
    public void SendAnswer(string from, string requestWas, string answer)
    {
        Clients.All.sendAnswer(from, requestWas, answer);
    }
```

note that `addMessage`is now changed to `sendAnswer` !